# dynamic cursor for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to create a dynamic plsql cursor for loop? The kind that doesn't require a fetch?

For example I usually define and loop through cursors in this way:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT *
      FROM employees;
BEGIN
   FOR row IN c1 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Name = ' || row.last_name);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I want to make the table name and where clause to be dynamic. So I'm thinking I need to concatenate a dynamic SQL string together use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it for the above type of cursor loop.

Comment: No, you would have to use open/fetch/close - but why is that a problem?

Comment: thanks @AlexPoole. Not a problem, just not something I've done before. I wanted to keep it a bit more simple and do it in the way I am familiar with before venturing into the unknown.